# Маска ввода телефона из нескольких input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как организовать такую маску ввода?

[image: скриншот]

Не могу найти готовое решение...

Comment: Может не совсем такой, но всё-таки сгодится? https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input

Comment: регулярками и триггер табуляции

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let parts = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-type="number"]')).sort((a, b) => +a.dataset.order > +b.dataset.order),
    data = [
      /^\+\d$/,
      /^\d{3}$/,
      [/^\d{3}\-\d\d\-\d\d$/, v => /^(\d{3})\-$/.test(v) ? RegExp.$1 : v.replace(/-/g, '').replace(/((?:^\d\d\d(?!-)|\d\d(?!$)))/g, "$1-")]
    ];

parts.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('input', check));
              
function check(){
  let id = +this.dataset.order;
  
  let regexp = Array.isArray(data[id]) ? data[id][0] : data[id],
      formatter = Array.isArray(data[id]) && data[id][1] ? data[id][1] : null;
  
  if(this.value.trim() === '')
    if(parts[id - 1])
      parts[--id].focus();
  
  if(formatter !== null){
    this.value = formatter(this.value);
  }
  
  if(regexp.test(this.value)){
    if(parts[id + 1])
      parts[++id].focus();
  }
}
```

```css
input[placeholder]{text-align: center;}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder{opacity: 1; transition: opacity 0.3s ease;}
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{opacity: 0; transition: opacity 0.3s ease;}
input:focus{outline: none;}
```

```html
<input type='text' data-type='number' data-order='0' size='1' maxlength='2' placeholder='+7' autofocus />
<input type='text' data-type='number' data-order='1' size='1' maxlength='3' placeholder='123' />
<input type='text' data-type='number' data-order='2' size='6' maxlength='9' placeholder='456-78-90' />
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```js
var code = document.getElementById('code');
var country = document.getElementById('country');
var number = document.getElementById('number');

countryHandler = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById('country').value;
  if(text.length > 1 && text[0] =='+'){    
       code.focus();
    }
};

codeHandler = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById('code').value;
  if(text.length > 2){    
       number.focus();
    } 
};

numberHandler = function() {
  var text = document.getElementById('number').value;
  if(text.length > 6){  
    //code.focus();
       number.blur();
    }
};


country.oninput = countryHandler;
country.onpropertychange = country.oninput;
code.oninput = codeHandler;
code.onpropertychange = code.oninput;
number.oninput = numberHandler;
number.onpropertychange = number.oninput;
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="country" id="country">
  <input type="text" name="code" id="code">
  <input type="text" name="number" id="number">
</form>
```

Тут конечно не учтены все условия, но думаю там понятно что нужно делать дальше.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую легковесное решение на чистом javascript - https://github.com/BankFacil/vanilla-masker

Подключение скрипта:

```
<head>
    <script src="/vanilla-masker.js"></script>
</head>
```

Использование в Вашем случае:

```
<input type="text" id="phone_country" placeholder="+7" maxlength="2">
<input type="text" id="phone_code" placeholder="123" maxlength="3">
<input type="text" id="phone_other" placeholder="123-45-67" maxlength="9">

...

<script>
    (function() {
        VMasker(document.getElementById("phone_country")).maskPattern('(+9');
        VMasker(document.getElementById("phone_code")).maskPattern('(999');
        VMasker(document.getElementById("phone_other")).maskPattern('(999-99-99');
    })();
</script>
```

Общая демка из исходников:

http://bankfacil.github.io/vanilla-masker/demo.html

И код общей демки из исходников:

https://github.com/BankFacil/vanilla-masker/blob/master/public/index.html

Comment: Вот теперь всё хорошо :)

Comment: в таком случае курсор не переносится на следующий input

Comment: Согласен, но и задачи такой не стояло. Поправьте свой вопрос в этом случае

Answer (score 1):

[JQuery Mask plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) - в конце body добавьте

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.date').mask('00/00/0000');
  $('.time').mask('00:00:00');
  $('.date_time').mask('00/00/0000 00:00:00');
  $('.phone').mask('+7(000)000-0000');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Добавьте в ответ рабочий код. Ссылка на ответ не является ответом!

Comment: в данном примере одно поле ввода, нужно 3

Comment: а разъединить потом значение 1 поля на 3 никак совсем да? всё относительно, как сказали бы физики - введи одно, получи 3 :-) можно ведь дойти до того, что и каждую цифру вводить в отдельное поле