# Помогите реализовать пару моментов

Tags: html5, css3

Подскажите пожалуйста, пару вопросов:

1. Реально такую формочку сделать "Акция! Только 18 дней" и каким образом ?
2. Как сделать границу которая доходит "Выезд дизайнера и дизайн-проект" и на этом прерывается ?

[image: IMG]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bg-action {
    min-height: 400px;
    background: url(http://cbsnews2.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/r/2017/01/01/5309e962-9cdf-414a-9725-86ecef4b4530/thumbnail/1200x630/2293ab016a39d09b16a77184387a8d4a/0101-sunmo-nature-butterflies-1221687-640x360.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;
}

.b-action {
    max-width: 970px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.b-action-info {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    background: #ddd;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    padding:
}

.b-action-info:before,
.b-action-info:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    background: #ddd;
}

.b-action-info:before {
    left: -20px;
    border-radius: 0 50% 0 50%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.b-action-info:after {
    right: -20px;
    border-radius: 50% 0 50% 0;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.b-action-info > span {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.b-form {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 25px auto;
}

.b-form fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<section class="bg-action">
    <div class="b-action">
        <div class="b-action-info">
            <span>Info action</span>
        </div>

        <form action="#" method="post" class="b-form">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Title form</legend>
                <input type="text" required>
                <input type="submit" value="send">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Работает в хроме, опере, в фаирфоксе легенда прижимается к левому краю :(

Comment: для firefox <legend align="center">Title form</legend>

Answer (score -1):

Заголовок "Выезд дизайнера и дизайн-проект" оформить отдельным DIV-ом, позиционировать его с помощью `position:relative` (например) и использовать `z-index:100` (чтобы элемент закрывал собой другие элементы).

```css
html, body, #entire-div { 
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
} 
#cont-div { 
    position:relative;
    top:25%;
    left:25%;   
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    border:2px solid red;
    background-color:gray;
    opacity:0.5;
} 
#frame-div { 
    width:80%;
    height:50%;
    margin:10%;
    margin-top:8%;
    border:2px solid white;
    background-color:yellow;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
    box-sizing: border-box;         
    padding:5%;
} 
#header-div { 
    position: relative; 
    display:block;
    width:20%;
    height:10%;
    top:30%; 
    left:40%;
    z-index:100;
    background-color:LightGreen;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id='entire-div'>
<div id='cont-div'>
<div id='header-div'>
    Attention!!!
</div>
<div id='frame-div'>
    Blablabla LA LA
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Потому что тут уже есть все секции для html, для css, для js. Я сделал правку.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас попробую, а что насчет первого вопроса? Такую форму реально создать ?

Comment: @YourDeveloper, я на первый вопрос уже отвечал недавно - jQuery.mask - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624201/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-input/624298#624298

Comment: @VostokSisters, спасибо, хотел понять как это делают ))

Comment: @EugeneBartosh что-то пошло не так) Attention просто залез вовнутрь и не перекрывает никого :(

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTEct.jpg

Comment: @EugeneBartosh А по первому вопросу, вы не так поняли, я хочу такую форму сделать в которой написано "Акция! .... " Её ведь обычным бордер радиусом не сделать.

Comment: @YourDeveloper, не знаю что там не так, но даже здесь уже работает этот код :-)) и называйте своими именами - это не форма а рамка, форма это то где элементы управления - <form>. Лучше всего нарисуйте такую картинку с прозрачными уголками и поставьте ее как фон, или наоборот фон прозрачный, а картинку с прозрачными углами вставить как img, поверх картинки текст